# Why is foreignKey generated in CamelCase?

Tags: sequelize.js

If use belongsTo and hasMany in the model the foreignkey for belongsTo is generated via CamelCase.

```
User.belongsTo(Group) -> foreignKey will be 'groupId'   
User.hasMany(Device)  

User.findAll({
  attributes: ['id'],
  include: [Group, Device] 
});
```

If don't use User.hasMany(Device) foreignKey for User.belongsTo(Group) will be 'group_id'.

```
User.belongsTo(Group) -> foreignKey will be 'group_id' 

User.findAll({
  attributes: ['id'],
  include: [Group] 
});
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Weird. Anyway I always indicate a foreign key in associations explicitly. You can try to do the same,.

Answer (score 1):

The different associates handle the column name generation slightly differently, but you should end up with the same formatting for the column when using the different methods. The Model options can also affect the association names, as different values will be set for the `target` and `source` when determining the `primaryKeyAttribute` and `options.name`.

***`././sequelize/lib/associations/belongs-to.js`***

```js
if (this.as) {
  // if you specify 'as' property...
} else {
  this.as = this.target.options.name.singular;
  this.options.name = this.target.options.name;
}

if (!this.foreignKey) {
  this.foreignKey = Utils.camelize(
    [
      // if you don't specify 'as' it will be this.target.options.name.singular
      this.as,
      this.target.primaryKeyAttribute
    ].join('_')
  );
}
```

The results of the `foreignKey` generation should be the same as below in `hasMany()`.

***`./sequelize/lib/associations/has-many.js`***

```js
if (!this.foreignKey) {
  this.foreignKey = Utils.camelize(
    [
      this.source.options.name.singular,
      this.source.primaryKeyAttribute
    ].join('_')
  );
}
```

This is what Utils.camelize() does.

```js
function camelize(str) {
  return str.trim().replace(/[-_\s]+(.)?/g, (match, c) => c.toUpperCase());
}
```